# I need a static public IP while using a router (to access a webpage)

Tags: php, tcp, nat

I have a static public IP which ISP gave me. The problem is, I have to use a router. When I do the IP changes to, say, 192.168.1.100. This is no use since no one outside my local network can reach the webpage. I've tried a program which converts this IP into a static one (not sure what it does really, the name of the program is Portforward Setup Static IP Address). All it did, it changed my IP to 192.168.1.50 and assured it was a static IP. It might be so, but I still can't reach the webpage outside my network.

How could I set up my router so that outsiders could reach my webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy. All you need is to setup [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on your router to forward ports `80` and `443` (in your case, as you want webpage access). Don't worry about doing anything else (but you will still have to properly setup httpd server) as you will have your static IP as public IP address but not your local, which is `192.168.1.50`.

To make sure that you're having expected public IP, just type in Google:

> IP

as a result you should have:

> Your public IP address is 1.2.3.4

Comment: Also in apache I configured so that it would use not 80 but 666 port, I guess I have to port forward this as well?

Comment: Not as well but only the ports that you want for external users. Just forward 666 port then.

Comment: Remember that in this case your users would have to know where to connect. I wouldn't recommend changing default httpd port as it changes nothing!

Comment: Well I used to connect to a webpage like this
    http://192.168.1.50:666/
In the httpd.conf I use these parameters:
    Listen 666
    ServerName localhost:80

Is this in any way correct?

Comment: `Listen` - what httpd is monitoring for connections. `Localhost:80` is the part of default settings. You should refer to your httpd's manual. It's relatively easy to setup.